# How do I find my questions that I have self-answered?

Tags: support, search, self-answer

I am trying the following search string, but it is returning all answered questions.

```
user:me is:question is:answer hasaccepted:yes
```

How can I search for my questions that I self-answered?

Comment: You mean your questions answered by you ? Or, do you mean your questions with a solution provided with your answer ?

Comment: Here you go : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135675/is-it-possible-to-search-self-answers-using-the-advanced-search

Comment: @TimWilkinson: Because that includes those answers that were not self-answers? I have 5,003 answers and don't much fancy sorting through them by hand. Not quite so bad for you, with your 34. :)

Comment: `is:question is:answer` is a bit absurd...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look at the sidebar (that tells you what you are searching for exactly), you will see that you can only filter for questions OR answers. It always uses the last option in the search.

There is no way to do what you want in the search bar. Since *I* have very few questions, *I* would click through all of my questions (that have at least 1 answer) and see which ones I answered. This may not be the best option for *you*, however.

You can use the SEDE query that the answer in Sunshine's link gives:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/131059/advanced-search-for-answers-posted-to-your-questions

Hopefully you remember which questions of yours you answered since Sunday because SEDE updates weekly.